# Consulta where EF Net core 3

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, net

Tengo el siguiente modelo:

```
public class Personas
{
    [Key]
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Nombre{ get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int edad { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public EstadoCivil estado{ get; set; }
}
```

Ahora quiero una consulta que me devuelva los que se llamas Jose y mayores de 18

```
Personas= await _db.Personas.Where(c => c.Nombre == "Jose").Where(c => c.edad > 18).ToListAsync();
```

Mi pregunta es, supongamos que el nombre y la edad pueden venirme o no, además el nombre quiero que sea un like. ¿ Cómo sería la consulta?

```
if (nombre) {}
if (edad) {}
```

Comment: ¿Cómo supongamos que el nombre y la edad pueden venirte? no esta muy clara la duda que tenes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no sabes si los parámetros llegan vacíos, lo podes manejar usando la interface [`IQueryable<T>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.linq.iqueryable-1?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(System.Linq.IQueryable%601);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8), y luego, realizar las validaciones de los diversos campos, ya que de esta manera, podrías ir armando la query progresivamente.

Vamos a lo práctico..

Primero, creamos un [`IQueryable<T>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.linq.iqueryable-1?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(System.Linq.IQueryable%601);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8), y lo igualamos al [`DbSet<Persona>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbset-1?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet%601);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=efcore-2.1) de tu [`DbContext`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=efcore-2.1)

```
IQueryable<Persona> Persona = _db.Personas;
```

Hasta aquí, la query no se realizó, por lo que acá empezaremos a agregar los filtros basados en condiciones, primero, validamos que haya llegado el parámetro `Nombre`, y, si es el caso, lo agregamos a la Query.

```
if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(paramNombre))
    Persona = Persona.Where(x => x.Nombre == paramNombre);
```

A esta altura, nuestro `IQueryable<Persona>` contiene una query, donde se valida que el resultado debe tener el mismo nombre que recibimos en el parámetro `paramNombre`, pero.. aún no se ejecuta..

Ahora sigamos el ejemplo validando la edad..

```
if(paramEdad!=null)
    Persona = Persona.Where(x => x.Edad == paramEdad);
```

A esta altura, tenemos, en el objeto `IQueryable<Persona>` la información que generará una query, donde existirá un `Where`, según si los parámetros llegaron o no.

Ahora, para ejecutar la query, simplemente debemos usar alguno de los métodos de IQueryable, como puede serlo, `ToListAsync()` en tu caso

```
IList<Persona> ListaResultante = await Persona.ToListAsync(); //En este momento se ejecuto la query realmente!
```

---

Para agregar a la pregunta, ya que mencionas el operador `LIKE`..

Si buscas tener un resultado igual a `LIKE` debes usar el método [`String.Contains(string param)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(System.String.Contains);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8), que devolverá verdadero siempre que exista una parte del parámetro dentro de la cadena.

Al igual que [`String.StartsWith(string param)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.string.startswith?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(System.String.StartsWith);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8) que sólo será verdadero, si el parámetro coincide con el comienzo de la cadena, o [`String.EndsWith(string param)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.string.endswith?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(System.String.EndsWith);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8) que solo lo hará si la cadena finaliza con el parámetro

Comment: Entiendo la consulta me funciona, pero no se como introducir el like:
Persona = Persona.Where(x => x.Nombre == String.Contains(nombre));

Comment: Es una función de extensión!, sería, por ejemplo `Persona.Where(x => x.Nombre.Contains(nombre)` se entiende?

Comment: Entendido, muchas gracias!